# Can we login+logout Magento admin programmatically by PHP script only

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin, programmatically, logout

Can we login+logout Magento admin by simple PHP code which presents outside Magento setup. I need this functionality because my requirement only full fills by this scenario only.

mywebsite.com/magentosetup (Magento setup here)
mywebsite.com/hitme.php (I need a custom script here for login and logout)

How can I do this with PHP+magento code customization?

For logout, I find this [example link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514023/magento-force-admin-user-log-out) but this code does not work for me.

I checked the code in Indexcontroller of Magento for logout function here only these lines are present.

```
$adminSession = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');    
$adminSession->unsetAll();     
$adminSession->getCookie()->delete($adminSession->getSessionName());
$adminSession->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('You have logged out.'));
$this->_redirect('*');
```

But this line of code is not working externally for logout externally. When echo this line in Magento section

```
$adminSession->getSessionName()
```

it provides "adminhtml" but the same line externally PHP file it provides "PHPSESSID". Let me know what can I do for login and logout admin programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Below is code that worked on my EE dev box to log you out of the admin:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));
$session->unsetAll();
$session->getCookie()->delete($session->getSessionName());
```

I tested this code and it worked on my EE dev box, but I lifted it from this answer: [Programatically login admin into admin panel possible or not](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86961/programatically-login-admin-into-admin-panel-possible-or-not)

Be sure to set "yourusername" to the username of the user you wish to log in.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
$app = Mage::app('default');

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));

// supply username
$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->loadByUsername('yourusername');

if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->renewSecretUrls();
} 

$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setIsFirstVisit(true);
$session->setUser($user);
$session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success',array('user'=>$user)    );

if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo("logged in");
}
```

Comment: Login code is not working first time , after clear cache of browser.

Comment: Did you set "yourusername" to a legitimate username for your site?

Comment: If you are reloading the login/admin page, be sure you don't have a key in your url.  If you click "logout" it will add the key, and reloading the page won't work because the script sets up a new session.   Try pulling up just the admin url without any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you requiring `Mage.php` in your external files?

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
// make sure the path is right to app/Mage.php from this file
```

If not, you won't have access to the objects and functions to login and logout.

Comment: Yes i already include file but the problem is that i am not able to do login and logout admin from externally files as i used example but it is not working for me.