# Programatically login admin into admin panel possible or not

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login, programmatically

I am working on the script for the login of admin panel automatically into the admin panel. Here is code [link](http://dineshinmca.blogspot.in/2012/10/magento-how-to-login-to-magento-admin.html) which is used for automatically login admin user into the admin panel. But it is not working when I run simple code then it says authenticated but it is not login into admin area when I open admin then it lands to login page only. I also googled script and find this code see an image. In the block, I get my conditions but as I move to Magento page then again login page is present. Is this process is possible or not with customization.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your source, pretty much lifted my original SO Answer.

With that said be sure and make sure the `secretKey` info is being set and other session methods are defined and dispatching any events or else it won't work.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
$app = Mage::app('default');

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));

// supply username
$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->loadByUsername('adminusername');

if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
  Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->renewSecretUrls();
}

$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setIsFirstVisit(true);
$session->setUser($user);
$session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success',array('user'=>$user));

if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
  echo("logged in");
}
```

Source:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973134/magento-admin-login-through-curl

Comment: Not working it display "logged in" on page but when i open admin panel, it display login page.

Comment: Instead of `echo`ing try actually redirect to the admin URL instead?

Comment: Redirection is also not working. I dont understand only echo is working but as i redirect magento login page it display only login page.